# Restore Zimbra Mail Server from Server that crashed

Tags: centos, email, zimbra

I had a Zimbra installation which crashed due to Hard drive failure. The Zimbra was version 5. My backup was not good and so I did a fresh install and now I have managed to get the /opt/zimbra folder from the crashed hard drive. Is there anyone who can assist me in restoring or combining the current install with my backup? THe current install I have is version 8 of Zimbra. I want to combine the two so that users have access to their old mails. Old installation was a 32Bit CentOS 5 current is 64Bit CentOS 6.
P.s. Its the Open Source Version. ZCS

Answer (score 1):

I would set up a separate machine with the old OS and ZCS, export the mailboxes and load the contents into the new setup. You can also use `ldapsync` for that, or even pull each mailbox with a IMAP/POP client out locally, and then push the contents into the new mailbox. You'll lose the calendar this way though.

Combining the two servers on the file level will probably cause more problems than it's worth, especially given the huge gap in versions in use.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I got to installing the same version of Zimbra and the same OS i used but when i copied the backup folder and tried to restart zimbra the errors I get are in: mysql.server and postfix are not running. Kindly assist on that

Comment: If you need troubleshooting, I would suggest you go to the zimbra forums, the employees there are very helpful. At the very least you can post a new question, with logs and error messages